# EF 7 Unidirectional many-to-many error: Every skip navigation must have a configured foreign key

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, has-many

following [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many) i setup my objects in that way but got

```
OneTimeSetUp: System.InvalidOperationException : The skip navigation 'Contatore.Workflow1' doesn't have a foreign key associated with it. Every skip navigation must have a configured foreign key.
```

for Contatori property of Workflow class

while i add foregin key correctly

```
public class Workflow
{
    public required int Id { get;  set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Contatore> Contatori { get; set; } = new HashSet<Contatore>();
}

public class Contatore
{
    public override int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Contatore> ContatoriFigli { get; set; } = new HashSet<Contatore>();
    public virtual ICollection<Contatore> ContatoriPadri { get; set; } = new HashSet<Contatore>();
}



internal class ContatoreConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Contatore>
{
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Contatore> builder)
    {
        builder
            .ToTable($"NAT_{Costanti.CodiceApplicazione}_CONTATORE_003")
            .HasKey(c => c.Id)
            .HasName("NAK_DASH_003");

        builder.Property(b => b.Id)
            .HasColumnName("ID_003")
            .HasComment("Chiave primaria")
            .HasDefaultValueSql($"SYUNA{Costanti.CodiceApplicazione}.SEQ_{Costanti.CodiceApplicazione}_003.NEXTVAL");
        
        builder.HasMany(x => x.ContatoriFigli)
            .WithMany(x => x.ContatoriPadri)
            .UsingEntity("NAT_DASH_CONTATORE_LINKS_004",
                m => m.HasOne(typeof(Contatore)).WithMany().HasForeignKey("IdContatorePrincipale").HasPrincipalKey(nameof(Contatore.Id)),
                s => s.HasOne(typeof(Contatore)).WithMany().HasForeignKey("IdContatoreCollegato").HasPrincipalKey(nameof(Contatore.Id)),
                j => {
                    j.Property("IdContatorePrincipale").HasColumnName("ID_CONT_PRINC_004");
                    j.Property("IdContatoreCollegato").HasColumnName("ID_CONT_COLL_004");
                    j.HasKey("IdContatorePrincipale", "IdContatoreCollegato");
                }
            );
    }


internal class WorkflowConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Workflow>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Workflow> builder)
    {
        builder
            .ToTable($"NAT_DASH_WORKFLOW_005")
            .HasKey(c => c.Id)
            .HasName("NAK_DASH_005");

        builder.Property(b => b.Id)
            .HasColumnName("ID_005")
            .HasComment("Chiave primaria")
            .HasDefaultValueSql($"SYUNA{Costanti.CodiceApplicazione}.SEQ_{Costanti.CodiceApplicazione}_005.NEXTVAL");
               
        builder.HasMany(x => x.Contatori)
            .WithMany()
            .UsingEntity("NAT_DASH_WORKFLOW_CONTATORE_006",
                m => m.HasOne(typeof(Workflow)).WithMany().HasForeignKey("ID_WORKFLOW_006").HasPrincipalKey(nameof(Workflow.Id)),
                s => s.HasOne(typeof(Contatore)).WithMany().HasForeignKey("ID_CONTATORE_006").HasPrincipalKey(nameof(Contatore.Id))

            );
    }
```

Oracle table:

```
CREATE TABLE "NAT_DASH_WORKFLOW_CONTATORE_006"
   (    
    "ID_WORKFLOW_006" NUMBER (9,0),
    "ID_CONTATORE_006" NUMBER (9,0), 
    CONSTRAINT NAF_DASH_006_004 FOREIGN KEY (ID_WORKFLOW_006) REFERENCES NAT_DASH_WORKFLOW_005 (ID_005),
    CONSTRAINT NAF_DASH_006_005 FOREIGN KEY (ID_CONTATORE_006) REFERENCES NAT_DASH_CONTATORE_003 (ID_003)
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by the `UsingEntity` configuration

```cs
builder.HasMany(x => x.Contatori)
    .WithMany()
    .UsingEntity("NAT_DASH_WORKFLOW_CONTATORE_006",
        m => m.HasOne(typeof(Workflow)).WithMany().HasForeignKey("ID_WORKFLOW_006").HasPrincipalKey(nameof(Workflow.Id)),
        s => s.HasOne(typeof(Contatore)).WithMany().HasForeignKey("ID_CONTATORE_006").HasPrincipalKey(nameof(Contatore.Id))

    );
```

Note that in all `UsingEntity` overloads expect first *right* relationship configuration, then *left*, and finally optionally the join entity itself.

In this case, the `left` is `Workflow` (the one on which you call `HasMany`) and *right* is `Contatore` (the one on which you call `WithMany`), but your fluent configuration is the exact opposite.

So simply exchange them and the issue will be solved

```cs
builder.HasMany(x => x.Contatori)
    .WithMany()
    .UsingEntity("NAT_DASH_WORKFLOW_CONTATORE_006",
        s => s.HasOne(typeof(Contatore)).WithMany().HasForeignKey("ID_CONTATORE_006").HasPrincipalKey(nameof(Contatore.Id)),
        m => m.HasOne(typeof(Workflow)).WithMany().HasForeignKey("ID_WORKFLOW_006").HasPrincipalKey(nameof(Workflow.Id))
    );
```

Also consider doing the same for the other many-to-many relationship shown. Because while it does not produce error, the meaning of the collection navigation properties (and their content) would be exactly the opposite of what is intended.

Answer (score 1):

It is sensitive to order (i.e. you need to setup right and left sides of the relationship in specific order, see the parameter names), change the `Workflow` configuration to:

```
builder.HasMany(x => x.Contatori)
    .WithMany()
    .UsingEntity("NAT_DASH_WORKFLOW_CONTATORE_006",
        s => s.HasOne(typeof(Contatore)).WithMany().HasForeignKey("ID_CONTATORE_006").HasPrincipalKey("Id"),
        m => m.HasOne(typeof(Workflow)).WithMany().HasForeignKey("ID_WORKFLOW_006").HasPrincipalKey("Id")
    );
```

Comment: It doesn't "seem", the parameters are called "configureRight" then "configureLeft".  So as soon as you realize which is left and which is right...  :) That's why I don't like `UsingEntity` API, even thought it has 20+ (!) overloads.

Comment: @IvanStoev yes, I saw the names and  I'm a bit lazy today to go deeper to understand what is left and right) Also I don't like the API too)

Comment: @IvanStoev reply was more detailed but thanks